# jQuery multiselect with header and default selected item

Tags: jquery, html, multi-select

I want to combine multiselect with header and default value. But my header can't show up.

```
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/multi-select.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <select multiple="multiple" id="my-select" name="my-select[]">
      <option value='elem_1'>elem 1</option>
      <option value='elem_2'>elem 2</option>
      <option value='elem_3'>elem 3</option>
      <option value='elem_4'>elem 4</option>
    </select>
    <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/jquery.multi-select.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#my-select').multiSelect();
        $('#my-select').multiSelect({    
              selectableHeader: "<div class='custom-header'>Selectable Members</div>",
              selectionHeader: "<div class='custom-header'>Selection members</div>", 
            });
        $('#my-select').multiSelect('select', [ 'elem_1']);
    });
    </script>
  </body>
```

By the way, my switch.png didn't show up too, if you know why, please guide me.

[image]

Comment: Please post the complete code here that is relevant to your question(s). Thanks.

Comment: Which script are you using? The one by Louis Cuny?

Comment: A [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) would help.